# How to center align ion icon inside button?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have this html structure:

```
<ion-view view-title="Items">
<ion-content>

<div class="card">
    <a href="#/app/item1" class="item item-text-wrap item-button-left">
        <button class="button circle text-center">
            <i class="ion-crop"></i>
        </button>
        Item 1
    </a>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <a href="#/app/item2" class="item item-text-wrap item-button-left">
        <button class="button circle text-center">
            <i class="ion-social-buffer"></i>
        </button>
        Item 2
    </a>
</div>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And I've added this custom css:

```
.circle {
    background-color: #00f;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    width: 50px!important;
    height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
.circle i {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

But it displays this way:

[image]

How can I do the `cards` to take the correct height and the `ion-icons` to the button's center?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For one, you could set `line-height` of `.circle` to `50px`.

Comment: try adding `position: relative;` to the `.circle`

Comment: @Aaron. It didn't work.. I think ionic uses a default `flex` style to the card. I don't know how to workaround it.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski. It worked in `.circle i`, now the icon is center aligned, thank you :)

Comment: Please note though that this solution may not work in Internet Explorer if you won't set the icon height.

Comment: I'm using ionic.. it will be displayed in android and ios... only webkit platforms

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can either set `text-align` to `center` and `line-height` to `50%` or try this:

```
.circle {
    background: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
    background: red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/41eo0he7/

Comment: The item went to the center, but the `card` still have the height problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should modify the `card` code as well (`height` etc).