# how to centralize button in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, sass, ionic2, center, centering

I want to centralize this button element in the center of the view

```
<button ion-button icon-only id="newTrip">
<ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

is there any built-in directive to centralize it without editing in the scss file ?

Comment: Take a look at the FAB component. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#fabs

Comment: It's a good solution and worked well , thanq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the FAB component.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#fabs

Answer (score 1):

The `<center>` tag from html5 is used for vertical align, and will be only applied within a `<ion-row>`. So I think you need to change it in scss.

Have a look at: [How to center align ion icon inside button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609020/how-to-center-align-ion-icon-inside-button)

Comment: It is working, but it is used for vertical align, and will be only applied within a <ion-row>

Comment: Oh sorry. I have never used it before in a <ion-row>

Comment: I suggest you to edit your answer in order to help other people searching this question.